# Onclick history.push in child component in react. - Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a Child component that is rendered dynamically inside a  Parent component. **I have a onClick redirect** function in it. Whenever **I click on that**, I get a error message as show below. Then **I click again, page redirects to destination**

[image]

**child component**

```
const CategoryItem = ({ img, name, categoryLink, match,history }) => (
      <div className="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 cat-item" onClick={(event)=>{
        history.push(`${match.url}/${categoryLink}`)
      }}>
        <img src={img} className="format-image" />
        <h5 className="device-title">{name}</h5>
      </div>
);

export default withRouter(CategoryItem);
```

**Parent Component**

```
const Category = () => {
  return (
    <section className="app-section">
      <div className="app-container">
        <h2>Select Category</h2>
        <div className="app-row justify-content-center">
          {listOfCategories.map(({ image, name, link }) => {
            return (
              <ChildItem key={name} img={image} name={name} categoryLink={link}  />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default Category;
```

I have solved the cannot Update error by making child component a class component.

**My router components looks like this.**

```
class Router extends Component {
  render() {
    let routes = (
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${BASE_URL}`} exact component={HomePage} />
          <Route path={`${BASE_URL}/:categorySlug`} exact component={PlanPage} />
          <Route path={`${BASE_URL}/success/:sr_id`}  exact component={SrCreated}/>
          <Route path={`${BASE_URL}/:categorySlug/:cart_id`} exact component={CartPage} />
          <Redirect to={`${BASE_URL}`}  />
        </Switch>
    );

    return (
      <Layout>
        {routes}
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have solved the render function error by making Child Component as Class Component. but I have to click Twice to redirect for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of error depend on realization render of Route component, the error can be in this case:

```js
<Route path="..." render={(someProps) => {
  someFunction() // <-- it's not a good way to make some actions
  return <SomeComponent />
}} />
```

Can you share your router?